# How to make an array from JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

Couldn't think of better title.
Important to note: I'm new to js and I guess its the reason I can't figure it out by myself.

I have a JSON array returned from a database, the JSON array represent a set of points. 
Example of the JSON array:

```
var JSON_array = [{lat:1,lng:2}, {lat:1,lng:3},{lat:2,lng:3}...]
```

I want to make a different array whose elements will be a function and the variables of the function will be the elements from the JSON array, like so:

```
var coordinates = [
new google.maps.LatLng(1, 2),
new google.maps.LatLng(1, 3),
new google.maps.LatLng(2, 3),
....
];
```

I made a function using forEach that counts the elements of the JSON array (for learning and trying to find a way to what I want) but I cant think of a way make the array mentioned above.

Comment: you can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function

Comment: That example is not a JSON array. That is just simply an array. When your JSON parser is done parsing JSON, it is just an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Array `map` method:

```
var coordinates = JSON_array.map(function(coordinate) {
    return new google.maps.LatLng(coordinate.lat, coordinate.lng);
})
```

This method gives you an new array based on (1) the original array and (2) how you deal with each element. Here's more detailed [**doc**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for the method.

Comment: Clearly the best answer. `Array.prototype.map()` is available for all modern browsers, including IE9. http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/

Answer (score 3):

you can also use regular for loop

```
coordinates = [];
for(var i=0;i<JSON_array.length;i++){
    coordinates.push(new google.maps.LatLng(JSON_array[i].lat,JSON_array[i].lng));
}
```

Comment: straightforward way :-)

Answer (score 2):

For mapping element from one array to another you can use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function like

```
var JSON_array = [{lat:1,lng:2}, {lat:1,lng:3},{lat:2,lng:3}...];
var coordinates = JSON_array.map(function(el){ return new google.maps.LatLng(el.lat, el.lng)});
```

Answer (score 1):

As Grundy commented you can just do:

```
coordinates = JSON_array.map(function(x) {
                                 return new google.maps.LatLng(x.lat, x.lng);
                             });
```

You might want to get your nomenclature straight though, this has nothing to do with JSON.